# How to create a session variable based on time variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataset like this with timestamp and userid.

I want to create a "session" variable in such a way that I can specify a time (1 min or 2min) and for each userid if the next time within a user id is within this time (1 or 2 min or so)then both are recorded as same session. Basically I look at the first time and then calculate the diff of next time and if within 1 min then same session. Similary if session changes then we take that new session time as base time and calculate all subsequent visits time with respect to that new session time.

I want this time_frame to be like a variable which one can play with and not hardcoded.

I can do this in sql with window function. was wondering how to do this in pandas.

```
time company_id
    2018-10-23 00:01:23 113141P
    2018-10-23 00:01:29 113141P
    2018-10-23 00:07:37 113141P
    2018-10-23 00:22:23 113141P
    2018-10-23 00:23:10 113141P
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform` with `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
# If not in datetime format already:
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# sort_values('time') is there just in case it's not already sorted
df['session'] = (df.sort_values('time').groupby('company_id')['time']
                 .transform(lambda x: (x.diff() > '00:02:00')
                            .cumsum()))

>>> df
                 time company_id  session
0 2018-10-23 00:01:23    113141P        0
1 2018-10-23 00:01:29    113141P        0
2 2018-10-23 00:07:37    113141P        1
3 2018-10-23 00:22:23    113141P        2
4 2018-10-23 00:23:10    113141P        2
```

Comment: How did u calculate the time diff? Its from previous time?

Comment: From the previous line in each group, yes. You'll have repeating sessions across groups, though. If you want to process them later, you can groupby `company_id` and `session`

Comment: so the way I understand. Each session is for a company_id right? And the way it is calculated is it looks at the diff of current time with previous time and if it is more than 2 mins, it's then a new session. Is this correct? And yes I want to take a group of session+company_id to group them later

Comment: Ok I see u r sorting by time. But it should be sorted by time within a company_id right? We are creating session for each company_id so wud need time to be sorted within that and not overall?

Comment: For your first comment, that's right. For your second, if it is sorted to start with, it will also be sorted within each `company_id` when you use `groupby`, so you shouldn't have a problem. You can test this by mixing your rows up, you'll get the same result :)